# Nearest places from google places

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to show the nearest places in an particular location.I coded to show all places that are nearest to my location using google places api from google maps.

[Reference link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/)

But the problem is i want to show the places respecting to the category.
For eg: If i want to show hotels.then it have to show only the hotels nearest to my location.

Comment: in which technology use android or java script?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site ... i do not see [question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question) here ...

Comment: Android does not use the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Answer (score 0):

In the Google api you will have the place types that you what to show
[Google types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)

Place types link : https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

You can include multiple place types by separating each with a plus symbol (+):

```
keyword=coffee+internet
```

it gives almost proper result

Comment: This will work, but is not the intended use for [Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)

Answer (score 0):

As per the Places API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests), you can pass the `types` parameter with your Nearby Search request to filter your results by the [supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types):

*"types — Restricts the results to Places matching at least one of the specified types. Types should be separated with a pipe symbol (type1|type2|etc). See the list of [supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)."*

An example Nearby Search request filtered by `types=doctor|electrician`:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&rankBy=distance&types=doctor|electrician&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Answer (score 0):

go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and ensure that there is no android.jar or maps.jar directly included. You should only have Google Apia with at least maps.jar and android.jar as leaves.